# Оборот после ЕСЛИ

Tags: пунктуация

Если(,) появившиеся после счастливого столетия(,) течения, которые усложняют чистую религию, не свернули с истинного пути...
Надо ли обособлять оборот (запятые в скобках)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §46.2. Определительный оборот, стоящий перед определяемым существительным, не отделяется запятой от определяемого слова.

Оборот *появившиеся после счастливого столетия* определяет существительное *течения* и находится перед ним. Особые случаи и другие правила тут не применяются, поэтому действует общая схема:

*Если появившиеся после счастливого столетия течения, которые усложняют чистую религию, не свернули с истинного пути (...)*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.